# Is there explicit formulas for this two sequences?

Tags: recurrence-relations

I know that $C(1) = P(1) = 1$ and also I have :
$$ \begin{cases}
  C(n) = n P(n - 1) + n(n-1) C(n-1) \\
  P(n) = n P(n - 1) + \dfrac{n(n-1)}{2} C(n - 1)
 \end{cases}
$$

Can you tell me if there is any chance to find an explicit formula for $C(n)$ and $P(n)$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $P(n)=C(n)-\binom{n}{2}C(n-1)$. This gives a linear recursion for $C(n)$ alone.

Comment: Hello and sorry for this so late answer. It remains the problem of finding a special solution but I will try to work with a linear recursion for $P(n)$. When  I asked my question, I was thinking about a general method.

Comment: Indeed, here I think that a straight calculation can gives something interesting. I'm working on it.